# How to get to total number of lines in an environment

Tags: counters, algorithmicx, totcount

While trying to figure a complete answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448941/141947), I was wondering how I could get the total amount of lines in the `algorithmic` environment.

Of course this question can be relevant for other environments.

I already tried with the `totcount` package but when trying to use the final value of a counter  with `\totalvalue{<counter>}` inside a 
`\makeatketter ... \makeatother` it fails.

I'm pretty sure I am missing some basic thing so  would like to understand this issue better.

Other previous answers e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109216/141947) for instance address this issue for other environments but I could not figure how to adapt them to this case.

Here is the MWE adapted from [the post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448941/141947) I am trying to answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\regtotcounter{ALG@line}

% Patch the line numbering to display the first and last line numbers
\makeatletter
\def\ALG@step%
   {%
   \addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}%
   \addtocounter{ALG@rem}{1}%
   % Beginning of patch
   % First line
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@line}}{1}}%
      {\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
      {}%
   % Last line  --> DOES NOT WORK
%   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@line}}{\arabic{\total{ALG@line}}}}%
%      {\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
%      {}%
   % End of patch
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@rem}}{\ALG@numberfreq}}%
      {\setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
      {}%
   }%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
See \figurename{~\ref{fig:myalgorithm}} below.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \noindent \textbf{Algorithm} itsname
 \noindent\hrule
 \begin{algorithmic}[3]
  \Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
  \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
  \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
  \EndFor
  \State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
  \Repeat
  \For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
  \For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
  \State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
  \State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \State $l'(i) \leftarrow min$
  \EndFor
  \State $changed \leftarrow l \not= l'$
  \State $l \leftarrow l'$
  \Until{$\neg changed$}
  \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \caption{This algorithm was copied from the algorithmicx's package documentation.}\label{fig:myalgorithm}
\end{figure}

Total amount of lines in the algorithm: \total{ALG@line}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use a two run solution saving the highest counter number of the current environment. How else should the line number printing command know it's the last one.

Comment: One could do so by adding stuff to `\endalgorithmic` (e.g. with `etoolbox` and `\AtEndEnvironment`), but you'd have to take care that you get a separate marker for each `algorithmic`, e.g. by using another counter.

Comment: @Skillmon, I would also use a two step process, hence the `totcount` package. However, I can't figure how to provide the stored value to the definition of `\ALG@step` so it can be used for some logical test

Comment: So the goal to fix your \ALG@step, not get the number of lines (`\arabic{ALG@line}`).

Comment: @JohnKormylo. Well it's both. I know how to patch `\ALG@step`, but i don't know how to provide the total amount of lines in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a two-run approach solving your issue. I permit you to use it in order to answer the other question, but please give me credit :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\regtotcounter{ALG@line}

% Patch the line numbering to display the first and last line numbers
\makeatletter
% execute this code at \end{algorithmic} but before the group is closed
\AtEndEnvironment{algorithmic}{\@WriteAlgorithmicLastLine}
% execute this code at \begin{algorithmic} just after the group is opened
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\stepcounter{AlgorithmicEnvironmentCounter}}
\newcounter{AlgorithmicEnvironmentCounter}
\newcommand*\@WriteAlgorithmicLastLine
  {% this macro writes the definition to the aux file, you have to make sure
   % that only the right stuff is expanded (\write expands its argument as
   % much as it is able to)
    \immediate\write\@auxout
      {%
        % we don't want \expandafter to disappear
        \unexpanded{\expandafter\gdef}%
        % we don't want \csname to do its work just here
        \unexpanded{\csname @AlgorithmicLastLine@}%
        % the counter should be expanded
        \the\c@AlgorithmicEnvironmentCounter%
        % \endcsname isn't expandable (if you're unsure whether something is
        % expandable enclose it by \unexpanded or precede it with \noexpand)
        \endcsname%
        % this counter should as well be expanded
        {\arabic{ALG@line}}%
      }%
  }
\def\ALG@step%
  {%
    \addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}%
    \addtocounter{ALG@rem}{1}%
    % Beginning of patch
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@rem}}{\ALG@numberfreq}}%
      {\setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
      {% if it is no line that already gets a number one of the other rules
       % might apply
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@line}}{1}}%
          {\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
          {% if not the first line, it may be the last
            % \ifcsdef is a wrapper around \ifcsname to check whether something
            % is defined or not
            \ifcsdef
              {@AlgorithmicLastLine@\arabic{AlgorithmicEnvironmentCounter}}%
              {% if it is defined execute this code
                % \ifnum is a TeX primitive comparing the following two numbers
                % and executing the true branch if the comparison is true,
                % possible comparisons are '=', '>' and '<'.
                \ifnum
                  % csuse is a wrapper around \csname building the
                  % control-sequence which's name is the argument of \csuse
                  % (argument is fully expanded)
                  \csuse
                    {%
                      @AlgorithmicLastLine@%
                      \arabic{AlgorithmicEnvironmentCounter}%
                    }%
                  =\c@ALG@line
                  \alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}%
                \fi
              }%
              {}% not defined
          }%
      }%
   }%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
See \figurename{~\ref{fig:myalgorithm}} below.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \noindent \textbf{Algorithm} itsname
 \noindent\hrule
 \begin{algorithmic}[3]
  \Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
  \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
  \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
  \EndFor
  \State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
  \Repeat
  \For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
  \For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
  \State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
  \State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \State $l'(i) \leftarrow min$
  \EndFor
  \State $changed \leftarrow l \not= l'$
  \State $l \leftarrow l'$
  \Until{$\neg changed$}
  \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \caption
  {%
    This algorithm was copied from the algorithmicx's package documentation.%
    \label{fig:myalgorithm}%
  }
\end{figure}

Total amount of lines in the algorithm: \total{ALG@line}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \noindent \textbf{Algorithm} itsname
 \noindent\hrule
 \begin{algorithmic}[3]
  \Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
  \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
  \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
  \EndFor
  \State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
  \Repeat
  \For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
  \For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
  \State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
  \State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \State $l'(i) \leftarrow min$
  \EndFor
  \Until{$\neg changed$}
  \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \caption
  {%
    This algorithm was copied from the algorithmicx's package documentation.%
    \label{fig:myalgorithm2}%
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I've added some comments in the above code hopefully describing everything.

**EDIT 2:** Solving the bugs of multiple line numberings.

Comment: Well thanks Skillmon ! I checked `etoolbox` too but I just don't know enough of such commands to make a solution on my own.  If you could just add a few comments, to fully understand what you propose it would be perfect ! I will of course credit you in the initial post ;)

Comment: @BambOo see my edits, I hope the comments are enough, if anything remains unclear just ask.

Comment: Thanks. There is still a small glitch, but  let me try to find myself so I can take a bit of credit ^^. FYI, the last line may be print twice due to the redundancy bteween your patch and `\ALG@numberfreq`

Comment: @BambOo you're right, but that is easy enough to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Since counters are saved globally, all you need is `\arabic{ALG@line}`.  If you want to access it before it is computed, you can fake a `\label`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
See \figurename{~\ref{fig:myalgorithm}} below (\ref{ALGlines} lines).

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \noindent \textbf{Algorithm} itsname
 \noindent\hrule
 \begin{algorithmic}[3]
  \Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
  \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
  \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
  \EndFor
  \State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
  \Repeat
  \For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
  \For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
  \If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
  \State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
  \State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
  \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \State $l'(i) \leftarrow min$
  \EndFor
  \State $changed \leftarrow l \not= l'$
  \State $l \leftarrow l'$
  \Until{$\neg changed$}
  \EndProcedure
 \end{algorithmic}
 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}
 \caption{This algorithm was copied from the algorithmicx's package documentation.}\label{fig:myalgorithm}
 \addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}\refstepcounter{ALG@line}\label{ALGlines}%
\end{figure}

Total amount of lines in the algorithm: \arabic{ALG@line}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. The last sentence is there just for example. The issue is in the patch for `algorithmicx` that I am trying to provide.